# MySQL where condition on index is slowing down query?

Tags: mysql

Hi I have written a MySQL query which is shown below.

```
SELECT device_uuid,
     day_epoch,
     hour,
     zone_id,
     is_repeat,
     (day_epoch + (3600*hour)) AS hour_epoch
FROM tracking_daily_stats_zone_unique_device_uuids_per_hour
WHERE day_epoch >= 1552435200
AND day_epoch < 1553040000
AND venue_id = 46
AND zone_id IN (102,105,108,110,111,113,116,117,118,121,287)
```

I have came across a strange issue which has confused my understanding of MySQL. When I run the above query which is using the `venue_id` (index) the run time takes around 30 seconds.

When I remove the `venue_id` condition and keep everything else the same the run time is reduced down to 9 seconds.

Here is the explain when using the `venue_id` as you can see it is looking at one partition which I believe should be faster.

[image: venue_id explain]

Here is the explain which isn't using the `venue_id` which is using all the partitions, which I would have thought should be slower

[image: no venue_id explain]

"The above image doesnt show all the partitions because if I showed all of them I wouldn't be able to screenshot it."

The above image doesnt show all the partitions because if I showed all of them I wouldn't be able to screenshot it.As you have probably already worked out the table data is partitioned on `venue_id` and the reason behind this was to speed the queries up.

Here is a screenshot of the indexes for this table:

[image: table indexes]

Comment: An index with a low cardinality (9) is kind of useless.

Comment: Sorry I am not a MySQL guru I just know how to write semi decent queries so this might be a dumb question. Would it be better to remove the ```venue_id``` index so it used the ```venue_id``` in the PK instead?

Comment: OK, it depends on the "selectivity" of each filtering condition. Now, you have three filtering conditions: by day_epoch, by venue_id, and by zone_id. Can you retrieve what percentage of rows each one separately retrieves from the total number of rows?

Comment: There is a total of 260938780 rows, day_epoch filter = 4266946, venue_id filter = 11654015 and zone_id filter = 11103307. I hope that helps

Comment: @Lukerayner - I have discussed this question in other variants that you have posted.